# Matlab kernel in Jupyter

Tags: python, linux, matlab, ipython, jupyter

I was trying to install a matlab kernel for my Jupyter notebook following [this directionon](https://github.com/Calysto/matlab_kernel), but when I do: `python -m matlab_kernel install`, it says: `Error executing Jupyter command 'kernelspec': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.`

I have previously installed an Octave kernel for Jupyter and the same command works fine so I wonder why is this command not working?